# Deployment to AppEngine stucks when uploading files

Tags: google-app-engine

When I'm trying to deploy a GWT-JAVA application to AppEngine, most of the time i'm running into timeout. It stucks for between 30 to 40 minutes trying to start the upload. Absolutely no network activity! Have not been able to find any solution around. I'm using App Engine SDK 1.8.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Help is very appreciated.

Here the output:

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/tmp/appcfg9154398045639640345.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Scanned 250 files.
    Scanned 500 files.
    Scanned 750 files.
    Scanned 1000 files.
    Scanned 1250 files.
    Scanned 1500 files.
    Scanned 1750 files.
    Scanned 2000 files.
    Scanned 2250 files.
    Scanned 2500 files.
    Scanned 2750 files.
    Scanned 3000 files.
    Scanned 3250 files.
    Scanned 3500 files.
    Scanned 3750 files.
    Scanned 4000 files.
    Scanned 4250 files.
    Scanned 4500 files.
    Scanned 4750 files.
    Scanned 5000 files.
    Scanned 5250 files.
    Scanned 5500 files.
    Scanned 5750 files.
    Scanned 6000 files.
    Scanned 6250 files.
    Scanned 6500 files.
    Scanned 6750 files.
    Scanned 7000 files.
    Scanned 7250 files.
    Scanned 7500 files.
    Scanned 7750 files.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 3215 static files.
    Cloned 2000 files.
    Cloning 4656 application files.
    Cloned 2000 files.
    Cloned 4000 files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 4111 files.       
#### HERE IT STUCKS FOR MORE THAN 30 MINUTES, NO ACTIVITY! WHY? ###
```

Comment: This happened to me once with Python appengine not sure if it applies for Java, you have to rollback the deployment because one of the deploys failed halfway through so everytime you try it gets stuck

Comment: Yes, after it failed I rollback and then sometimes its getting faster. Can the reason be about Indexing? When I try to deploy to a new account with no data in the datastore its likely to be faster.